# how to achieve double borders with adjacent divs that have angled border decorations

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create three separate containers with a "comic book strip" kind of feel. I would like the end result to look like this image with white borders surrounded by black boarders and have angled dividers between them:

[image]

This is the closest I've come to achieving this, however you will see that I'm missing the inner black borders. I'm also not sure how to draw the main black borders on top and bottom and allow breaks in them for the white to intersect. (Please run the snippet in Full Screen Mode):

```css
.container {
    width: 1020px;
}

.clear{clear:both; font-size:0px;line-height:0px; display:block;}

.categorycta {
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bandtop {
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
}

.bandbot {
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.categorycta .col {
 position: relative;
 height: 216px;
    width: 340px;
 float: left;
 background-size: cover;
}

.categorycta .col.left:after {
 content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 216px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.categorycta .col.mid:before {
 content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 216px solid #fff;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
}

.categorycta .col.mid:after {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 216px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 0;
}

.categorycta .col.right:before {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 216px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bandtop"></div>
<div class="categorycta">
    <div class="col left" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/220/');">

    </div>
    <div class="col mid" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/222/">
    </div>
    <div class="col right" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/225/">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="bandbot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include you three images? so we can give an example in snippet

Comment: The images I'm testing with are included in the code. I just used dummy images on lorempixel.com like this one: http://lorempixel.com/340/240/ Any image over 340 x 220 will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the existing borders, instead you can use `transform: skewX(2deg);` and add the black borders around it, use `margin-top` to cover up the top and bottom border.

**Example:**

```css
.container {
    width: 1020px;
}

.clear{clear:both; font-size:0px;line-height:0px; display:block;}

.categorycta {
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bandtop {
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
}

.bandbot {
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.categorycta .col {
 position: relative;
 height: 216px;
    width: 340px;
 float: left;
 background-size: cover;
}

.categorycta .col.left:after {
   content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 102%;
    /* border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; */
    /* border-top: 216px solid #fff; */
    /* border-left: 10px solid transparent; */
    /* border-right: 0 solid #fff; */
    background: white;
    transform: skewX(2deg);
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
}

.categorycta .col.mid:before {
 content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 216px solid #fff;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
}

.categorycta .col.mid:after {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 102%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -9px;
    background: white;
    transform: skewX(-3deg);
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.categorycta .col.right:before {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 216px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bandtop"></div>
<div class="categorycta">
    <div class="col left" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/220/');">

    </div>
    <div class="col mid" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/222/">
    </div>
    <div class="col right" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/340/225/">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="bandbot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? It may not be the tidiest solution but it looks almost the same as in your picture.
You can adjust some values to your liking, I mostly used clip-path. A black background and the image over it in a bit smaller size.

```css
.container {
    width: 1020px;
}

.categorycta {
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
 background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 220px;
}

.comic-panel {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 222px;
  position: absolute;
}

.comic-left {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.comic-left > img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 89% 1%, 99% 99%, 1% 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 89% 1%, 99% 99%, 1% 99%);
}

.comic-middle {
  left: 340px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);
}

.comic-middle > img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 99% 1%, 89% 99%, 11% 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 99% 1%, 89% 99%, 11% 99%);
}

.comic-right {
  left: 680px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.comic-right > img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(9% 1%, 99% 1%, 99% 99%, 11% 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(9% 1%, 99% 1%, 99% 99%, 11% 99%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="categorycta">
    <div class="comic-panel comic-left">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/340/220/">
    </div>
    <div class="comic-panel comic-middle">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/340/222/">
    </div>
    <div class="comic-panel comic-right">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/340/225/">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obligatory CanIUse reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path .... note no Microsoft support

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the **clip-path** property.

Firstly you remove all borders from the inner images, then you display them as inline-block (and set the parent element font-size to 0 to avoid display issues).

Then you create a clip path for each of the different types of tiles you are going to need. For example:

```
.left{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Rather than having the image as background, you use an img tag. The size of the image is equal to the size of the container minus the border (for example, if your container is 200 x 175px and you wish your border to be 5px wide, you set the image as 190 x 165px). Lastly, you apply the same clip-path to the image itself.

**In short, you do not really use borders. You simulate them by creating an image that is slightly smaller than the container and centering it.**

```
.col img {
    position: absolute;
    left:5px; /* Desired thickness of your border */
    top: 5px; /* Desired thickness of your border */
    width: 190px; /* Width of the container minus the thickness of the border multiplied by two*/
    height: 165px; /* Heightof the container minus the thickness of the border multiplied by two*/
}   

.left img {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Here's a Jsfiddle (I used red borders for visibility and included five images rather than three to show all the possible types of tiles you may need to use):

https://jsfiddle.net/rsjc1pL4/

Comment: Obligatory CanIUse reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path .... note no Microsoft support